# margin: 0 auto not working

Tags: html, css, margin

What exactly is needed for margin: 0 auto to work? It usually works for me but for some reason in this particular case I can't center my navigation menu.
Fiddle attached below.

```css
.item-list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.item a {
  color: #37302b;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header {
  position: inherit;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="desktop-nav">
    <ul class="item-list">
      <li class="item active">
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/gross-daily/main.html" data-scroll>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/gross-daily/main.html" data-scroll>Newest</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#projects" data-scroll>Most Popular</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#projects" data-scroll>Categories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#blog" data-scroll>Stash</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item" onclick="showSearch();">
        <a href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wwf1at2n/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using flexbox, you can add `justify-content: center` to your `.item-list` rules (no margin: auto needed):

```css
.item-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.item a {
  color: #37302b;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header {
  position: inherit;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="desktop-nav">
    <ul class="item-list">
      <li class="item active">
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/gross-daily/main.html" data-scroll>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/gross-daily/main.html" data-scroll>Newest</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#projects" data-scroll>Most Popular</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#projects" data-scroll>Categories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#blog" data-scroll>Stash</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item" onclick="showSearch();">
        <a href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It works. :-) Did not know about that.

Comment: margin: 0 auto isn't a hack lol

Comment: @StefanBob fair enough; removed

Answer (score 1):

add `justify-content: center;` because you're using `display: flex`

Answer (score -1):

Block level element is needed for `margin: 0 auto;` to work in a normal scenario.

Comment: a width is need for margin auto to work because the defautl width is 100% and margin:auto will have no effect

Comment: You need a block level element for margin: 0 auto to take effect. It still works on width: 100% elements, there is just nothing to do.